# Moving multiple uploaded images

Tags: php

I scaled multiple images using `for` loop. Now I want to move those images into a folder.
How can I do that?

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'uploads/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
```

I have this code but only one image can be place in the uploads folder and the other images are missing.

Comment: I think `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` is an array if you have multiple images, so you need to loop trough them. Can you show the code you used to scale the images.

Comment: if ($originalWidth > $originalHeight) { $percentage = ($size / $originalWidth); 
} else { $percentage = ($size / $originalHeight); }
$temp_width = $originalWidth;
$temp_height = $originalHeight;

Comment: for ($i=1; $i <=$resize ; $i++) { $new = $album_name.$i."_".$target;
$targetWidth = round($temp_width * $percentage);
$targetHeight = round($temp_height * $percentage);
$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($target));
imagecopyresampled($targetImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
imagejpeg($targetImage,$new,80);
$temp_height = $targetHeight;
$temp_width = $targetWidth;}

Answer (score 0):

This code is working finr for me 
form.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
Image1: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
Image2: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Upload.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
$success = 0;
$fail = 0;

$uploads_dir = 'uploads';
$count = 1;
foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];
        $uploadfile = "$uploads_dir/$name";
        $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadfile,strlen($uploadfile)-3,3));
        if (preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|bmp)/",$ext)){
            $newfile = "$uploads_dir/picture".str_pad($count++,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).".".$ext;
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfile)){
                $success++;
            }else{
                echo "Couldn't move file: Error Uploading the file. Retry after sometime.\n";
                $fail++;
            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Extension.\n";
            $fail++;
        }
    }
}
echo "<br> Number of files Uploaded:".$success;
echo "<br> Number of files Failed:".$fail;
```